# @Autowiring give compilation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring security.I have created following test class for 
that

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
             .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() ;

            http.formLogin().loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll();
    }
```

Following piece of code gives me compilation error.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

It Says

> Could not Autowire .No Bean of AuthenticationManagerBuilder  Found .

I have followed  http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/ tutorial. Please pin Point where i am wrong .

Complete Stack Trace

```
11:27:51,490 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[local.testsecurity.com].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-3) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) [spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472) [spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:600) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:948) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:817) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 29 more

11:27:51,521 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[local.testsecurity.com].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-3) Servlet  threw load() exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:948) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:817) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605) [spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) [spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472) [spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
```

Comment: Is it compilation error or runtime exception?

Comment: It is a compilation error.When i run  , i am getting following runtime exception.  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Could you post your complete stacktrace? Stacktrace will definitely mention what caused the bean error..

Comment: That is not a compilation error. You only get compilation errors when the Java compiler compiles your code. You will not be able to run the code if you get a compilation error, because the compiler will not create the *.class files in case of a compilation error.

Comment: The Compiler shows a red mark  for code public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception .But class file is creating .May be it is a warning  .

Answer (score 1):

If AuthenticationManagerBuilder is not found, it seem to be problem with missing dependency. Double check if you have correct Spring Security dependency.

If AuthenticationManagerBuilder is found, but it gives you runtime error. It is most probably some problem in you Spring configuration. Hard to say where the problem is when you reveal partial configs.

BTW, If you are trying Spring Security for the first time, I would suggest to [follow this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/). It is configured for you out of the box and contain full source code. But it's using Spring Boot, so it may not be helpful for fixing configuration based on plain Spring.

Comment: @ikrnac.. Thats the fault.I was missing  some dependency.Thanks  for the hint

Comment: glad that it helped. you may want to accept/upvote answer that helped you solve you problem on SO.

Comment: Apologies..I don't have enough reputation for  upvote the solution ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Finally,  here is the solution for above problem.

I missed few  dependency jar.I had added following dependency jar

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Once i added following additional dependency, my code started working.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks Guys..